# Fabric.js animate sprites and text field

Tags: javascript, animation, fabricjs

about month ago i asked how to quee animatations for objects in Fabric.js to which i got response from @nickvans. This is the code. Based on this I changed the code and created with HTML5 drag and drop, aplication which allows you to give to each object on canvas its own set of different commands. Basicly creating moving scene. Mine 1st question is :if it is possible to also use sprites. So instead of the triangle in the exmaple below it would be animated sprite that would also change its position. And 2nd question is it possible to somehow add text field that would follow the object during its movement? Something like those comics bubles.
Thanks in advance for any tips

```
    function startAnimationQueue(animationQueue){
// queues up the animations for the shape

var runningDuration = 0; // variable that adds up the animationQueue durations
for (var i=0; i<animationQueue.length; i++){
    var animationDefinition = animationQueue[i];

    // Create a closure around the animationDefiniton so that each       setTimeout gets sequential animationDefinition inputs
    var fn = (function(animationDefinition){
        return function(){
            triangle.animate('left', animationDefinition.left, {duration: animationDefinition.duration, onChange:canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas)})
            triangle.animate('top', animationDefinition.top, {duration: animationDefinition.duration, onChange:canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas)})
            // Note: you can animate additional attributes here if you want, just add additional attributes to the objects in
            //   the animationQueue list. You could also have one of those inputs be the object to be animated in case you want
            //   to animate multiple objects using the same queue.
            };
        })

    // Create the timeout that will apply the transformations sequentially
    // If you want you could set the window.setTimeout to a variable that you could destroy if you need 
    // to interrupt the animation queue after you create it (but before it finishes)
    window.setTimeout(fn(animationDefinition), runningDuration);

    // set the next setTimeout duration to be .duration later than the previous one
    // this makes the second animation fire after the first one completes
    runningDuration += animationDefinition.duration;
}
    }
    document.onreadystatechange = function () {


if (document.readyState == "complete") {

    // I put the canvas init stuff in here because of (I think) a failed race condition or something that caused
    // your original method to fail in Chrome
    window.canvas = new fabric.Canvas('scene');

    window.triangle = new fabric.Triangle({
        width: 30
      , height: 30
      , fill: 'red'
      , left: 30
      , top: 0
    });

    window.canvas.add(window.triangle);
    window.canvas.renderAll();

    // Create a list of animations to apply
    var animationQueue = [
        {"left": "+=0", "top": "+=100", "duration": 1000},
        {"left": "+=55", "top": "+=0", "duration": 2000}

    ]

    // Apply the animations in sequence using window.setTimeout
    startAnimationQueue(animationQueue);
  }
}
```

and HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.4.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="scene" width="400" height="400" />
</body>
</html>
```